# Pessimistic concurrency with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, multithreading, entity-framework

In the documentation about Entity Framework is written that it doesn't support pessimistic concurrency out of the box. That's why there is no way to lock table when read entities from it using Linq to Entities syntax.

Let's imagine that we have next task: there are multiple threads that share one table in Database. Table has next structure:

```
Table Counter
Name : varchar[10]
Value : bigint
```

Every thread wants to get counter with name = "some name", get it's counter value, than increase it and save back to the database.

Here we can see problem that at one time all these threads can read the same value from database and increase it. Let's imagine that we have 5 threads. Initial counter value is 1. If all threads read counter, all of them get value 1. Then they increase it's value and save it back to the database. In the end we have counter value equals 2. But expected value was 6, because we want every thread get real value from database.

I thought that it was possible to solve this problem using transaction scope with high level of isolation like this:

```
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions{IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable}))
    {
        using (var context = new TestDbContext())
        {
            var counter = context.Counters.First();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            counter.Value ++;
            Console.WriteLine("Value={0}", counter.Value);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
```

Non of isolation levels allow us to lock table after reading records from it. In transact SQL we have UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK keywords that allows us to lock the table until transaction completes.
So I solve this problem created an extension method for DbContext:

```
public static class DataContextExtensions
{
    public static void LockTable<TEntity>(this DbContext context) where TEntity : class
    {
        var tableName = (context as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().EntitySet.Name;
        List<TEntity> topEntity = context.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(String.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * from {0} WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)", tableName)).ToList();
    }
}
```

And now I can use this method when I want to lock table after reading like this:

```
    using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions{IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted}))
    {
        using (var context = new FrontierDbContext())
        {
            context.LockTable<Counter>();
            var counter = context.Counters.First();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            counter.Value ++;
            Console.WriteLine("Value={0}", counter.Value);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
```

After that all threads that want to increase counter value will get actual value from database because they will wait until table will be free.

As I said it's my workaround and maybe I'm wrong somewhere. That's why I want to ask you to point to better solutions. Because I don't want to reinvent the wheel
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why optimistic concurrency cannot be used for this scenario?

Comment: That was my question. How can I solve this problem using Entity Framework?

Comment: Entity framework supports optimistic concurrency, you could apply the [Concurrency] attribute to your Value property, this should cause you to get a concurrency exception when a thread tries to update an older value of the counter,

Comment: I am in the same case, I would like to use pessimistic concurrency and the unique way that I find it is to use a first t-sql query to block and a second query to get the entities, to do the includes, work with them and later save the chages. With EF7 seems that we will can use hints with EF, so I hope to can avoid to use the query to block the rows.

Answer (score 0):

in your case you could use a workaround in the TransactionScope using block for this specific situation like this:

```
const string updateStr = "update table set counter = counter + 1";
context.ExecuteSqlCommand(updateStr);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It's not an option. Because my example was simplified to explain the problem. If you have business requirements more than just to increase a counter and for example to do more work with locking table, you will still have this problem